# Link domain to NGINX subdirectory location keeping domain in browser

Tags: nginx

To enter to my website, I use http://mydomain/webboss/ Here below you have how I set up this in my nginx config. However I've been asked to use a domain like http://boss-test.com.nl (this one is already set up to go to mydomain root)

default:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name _;

        include /etc/nginx/sites-available/subdirs/*;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/subdirs/webboss

```
location /webboss {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /webboss;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1200s;
        proxy_send_timeout 1200s;
        proxy_read_timeout 1200s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 1200s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1200s;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
                proxy_pass http://unix:/srv/webboss/run/webboss.sock;
                break;
        }
}

location / {
        return 301 http://mydomain/webboss;
}
```

What I need is to "redirect" http://boss-test.com.nl to /webboss but keeping in the browser url: http://boss-test.com.nl (so far it gets redirected to mydomain/webboss). BTW: both http://boss-test.com.nl and  http://mydomain/webboss/ must work.

Any ideas?

Comment: `so far it gets redirected` what is responsible for this redirect? Is that location block in both servers? Please update the question to address - though note this is more appropriate to ask on serverfault.com.

Comment: @AD7six I updated this.

Comment: Did you try using `proxy_pass` instead of `return 301`?

Comment: How is it unexpected that `return 301` results in a redirect? Please show the full server block for `http://boss-test.com.nl` instead of disconnected bits of it :).